# Permission Denied when Using [objshell browseforfolder] in vbs on html page

Tags: html, windows, web, vbscript, hta

I am trying to use [`objshell browseforfolder`] with vbs in HTML to make a folder browser. It is working fine in hta but when I put it into html page, it always show me that permission denied. I did some research on this, looks like IE does not support folder browse for security reason.....so my question is that is there anyway to make it work? I m using it on a internal page, so security wont be an issue.....

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language = "VBScript">
Sub ChooseSaveFolder_OnClick()
  strStartDir = "c:\work"
  userselections.txtFile.value = PickFolder(strStartDir)
End Sub 

Function PickFolder(strStartDir)
  Dim SA, F
  Set SA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set F = SA.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0, strStartDir)
  If (Not F Is Nothing) Then
    PickFolder = F.Items.Item.path
  End If
  Set F = Nothing
  Set SA = Nothing
End Function 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="userselections">
<input type = "text" name = "txtFile" size="50" />
<input type = "button" value = "Browse ..." Name="ChooseSaveFolder">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lowing down the security settings for Intranet zone might help.

Comment: Tried, wont help.....

Comment: Looks like if need to browse file system, can't be done from IE...HTA is a better solution for this.....